# What is the sum of integers from $1$ to $789999$ ? asks the professor

Tags: summation

How to resolve it? How to find that sum?

Comment: Ask Gauss the great! :-)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can we see your progress?

Comment: This is a sum of arithmetic progression.

Comment: 1+789999, 2+789998, 3+789997 etc. Good luck.

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{10} k = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10$$
$$= 0 + 10 + 1+9 + 2+ 8+ 3 + 7+4+6+ 5 $$
$$ = 5 \cdot 10 + 5 = 55= \frac{10(10+1)}{2}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{11} k = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 $$
$$= 11 +0 + 10 + 1+9 + 2+ 8+ 3 + 7+4+6+ 5 $$
$$ = 6 \cdot 11 = 66 = \frac{11(11+1)}{2}$$
etc

Can you see a pattern?

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEEEES!

Comment: Now *there's* some enthusiasm ...

Answer (score 2):

If you can find the **average** of those numbers, then multiply that by $789999$, then you've got it.

The average of $1$ and $789999$ is $\dfrac{1+789999}{2}=395000$.

The average of $2$ and $789998$ is $\dfrac{2+789998}{2}=395000$.

The average of $3$ and $789997$ is $\dfrac{3+789997}{2}=395000$.

If you can figure out why the pattern persists, and write an explanation of it, then you should be able to see what the average of all the numbers from $1$ through $789999$ is.

Answer (score 1):

$$1+2+3+\cdots+n=\sum_{i=1}^ni=\dfrac {n(n+1)}2 \\ \ \\ \text{in your case: }1+2+3+\cdots+789999=\dfrac{789999\cdot790000}{2}=312049605000$$